# Updating json array field by removing specific values in Postgres

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

Let's say I have a table called `SomeTable` with a primary key `row_id` and json array field called `some_json`.

`some_json` would look something like this:

```
[{'some_key': 'some_value_1'}, {'some_key': 'some_value_2'}, 
 {'some_key': 'some_value_3'}, {'some_key': 'some_value_4'}]
```

and I have a function that takes a text array parameter called `values_to_remove` like this:

```
['some_value_2', 'some_value_3', etc]
```

I want to update `some_json` by removing all of its json objects that contain a text value that's also in the `values_to_remove` array. I have a rough idea of what I need to do but don't know how to piece it all together with the correct syntax, so forgive me if doesn't make sense.

Here's what I have so far (forgive me for butchering the syntax):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION remove_json_items (removal_id smallint,        
                                              values_to_remove text[])
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE SomeTable
    SET some_json = array_to_json(array_remove(ARRAY(SELECT * 
                                                     FROM json_array_elements(some_json)), 
                                               (SELECT * 
                                                FROM json_array_elements(some_json), 
                                                     unnest(values_to_remove)
                                                WHERE some_json->>some_key = values_to_remove.value
                                  )))
    WHERE row_id = removal_id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

What's the correct solution for achieving this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function made with plain SQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION remove_json_items (removal_id smallint,        
                                              values_to_remove text[])
RETURNS void AS $$
    UPDATE sometable
    SET some_json =
       (SELECT json_agg(ae)
        FROM (
            SELECT json_array_elements(some_json) AS ae from sometable WHERE row_id = removal_id
        ) sq1
        WHERE NOT ARRAY[(SELECT * FROM json_to_record(ae) AS x(some_key text))] <@ ARRAY['some_value_3', 'some_value_2'])
        WHERE row_id = removal_id;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```